# Congruent number $23$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-geometry

The set of Congruent numbers are all the integer areas of rational sided right triangles. This means that if g is a Congruent number there exists some integer $n$ such that $g \cdot n^2$ is the integer area of an integer sided right triangle where n is the scaling factor applied to the original rational right triangle.

> My question is what is the smallest $n$ for $g = 23$?

Comment: It is $\;n=1\;$ ...:) But the sides of the straight triangle of which it is the area are a nightmare. Watch here: http://www.aimath.org/news/congruentnumbers/congruentnumbers.pdf

Comment: The sides are not integers, @Joanpemo  re-read the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, I missed that part. Well, in the posted link he can check the rational sizes of the sides and find out the $\;n\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you for the link. For 23 it gives n=72306780 and the right triangle has sides 279340175, 860959008, 905141617. Little wonder that I could not find this through a simple search of generated primitive right triangles.